# evaluate the integral involving $e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln 4} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2x}}}dx$$

I made the $u-$sub

$$u=e^{-x}$$
Then my limits become $1/2$ and $1/4$ and

$$du = - e^{-x} dx$$

so rewriting the integral I have

$$-\int_{1/2}^{1/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\sin^{-1}(u)\bigg\vert_{1/4}^{1/2}$$

but this is not the answer. The answer is $\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4})-\frac{\pi}{3}.$ I know $\sin^{-1}(1/2)=-\frac{\pi}{3}.$ But don't see how they get the $\sqrt{15}$.

Comment: In your last line $\sin^{-1} (u)$ and not $\sin^{-1} (e^{-x})$.

Comment: oh my gosh, I swapped limits but then plugged my $u$ back in smh!

Comment: @Essaidi what about the radical $15$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\left.\int_{1/4}^{1/2}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\arcsin y\right|_{1/4}^{1/2}=\arcsin\frac12-\arcsin\frac14$$

But $\;\arcsin x=\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;$ , so the above result equals

$$\arcsin\frac12-\arcsin\frac14=\arctan\frac1{\sqrt3}-\arctan\frac1{\sqrt{15}}=\frac\pi6-\arctan\frac1{\sqrt{15}}$$

which equals $\;\arcsin\frac{\sqrt{15}}4-\frac\pi3\;\ldots\;$

Comment: how did you know $\arcsin x$ $=$ $\arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$?

Comment: put $x = \sin \theta$ then :
$$\arctan \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \arctan \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = \theta = \arcsin x$$

Comment: @HossienSahebjameDifferentiate both sides and then evaluate at $\;x=0\;$ to find the constant...

Answer (score 2):

Notice that :
$$\int_{1/4}^{1/2} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} = -\left[\cos^{-1} u\right]_{1/4}^{1/2} = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{4} - \cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{2} = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{\pi}{3}$$
But we know that :
$$\cos^{-1} x = \sin^{-1} \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
then :
$$\int_{1/4}^{1/2} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} = \sin^{-1} \sqrt{1 - \dfrac{1}{16}} - \dfrac{\pi}{3} = \sin^{-1} \dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{4} - \dfrac{\pi}{3}$$